# Из синхронного сокета в асинхронный

Tags: c#, сокеты, .net, сокет

В MSDN есть замечательный пример получения кода html страницы ([пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)), но к сожалению в этом примере производится блокирование до тех пор, пока не будет принята вся страница. Если не сложно помогите пожалуйста переделать его под асинхронные сокеты, буду премного благодарен за помощь.

Сам пример:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class GetSocket
{
    private static Socket ConnectSocket(string server, int port)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        // Get host related information.
        hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        // Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
        // an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
        // (typical in the IPv6 case).
        foreach(IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
        {
            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
            Socket tempSocket = 
                new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            tempSocket.Connect(ipe);

            if(tempSocket.Connected)
            {
                s = tempSocket;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    // This method requests the home page content for the specified server.
    private static string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port) 
    {
        string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + server + 
            "\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
        Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];

        // Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
        Socket s = ConnectSocket(server, port);

        if (s == null)
            return ("Connection failed");

        // Send request to the server.
        s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

        // Receive the server home page content.
        int bytes = 0;
        string page = "Default HTML page on " + server + ":\r\n";

        // The following will block until te page is transmitted.
        do {
            bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
            page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
        }
        while (bytes > 0);

        return page;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        string host;
        int port = 80;

        if (args.Length == 0)
            // If no server name is passed as argument to this program, 
            // use the current host name as the default.
            host = Dns.GetHostName();
        else
            host = args[0];

        string result = SocketSendReceive(host, port); 
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно в вашем коде заменить блокирующий `socket.Connect()` на асинхронный `socket.BeginConnect()` с соответствующим коллбеком. *Пример такого действия вы можете посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms145128.aspx)*

*Предполагаю, что с переделкой данного кода вы вполне справитесь самостоятельно.*

---

Для тех же самых целей может использоваться и метод `ConnectAsync` у сокета. Разница - в используемых подходах, производительности и сложности реализации, детали и причины введения нового метода можно посмотреть [**здесь**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764921/whats-the-difference-between-beginconnect-and-connectasync) Если вкратце, то `ConnectAsync` более производителен и не требует лишних синхронизаций, **работает под сильверлайтом** *(в отличии от первого)*, но сложнее в написании и поддержке.

*Именно этот метод используется в вашем примере из комментариев.*

Comment: Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, есть разница между неблокирующими сокетами и асинхронными?
Кстати, нашел пример уже. Не знаю, на каких сокетах реализовано:
[Networking Samples for .NET v4.0](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nclsamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=socket%20performance) (описание на русском - [Пример технологии производительности сокета](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb907001%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). Но там не использовался `BeginConnect()`, значит ли что это менее производительно?

Comment: @nbit Неблокирующие и асинхронные - это синонимы. По поводу второго вопроса - см. обновление ответа.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробные разъяснения!